# Unit / Integration tests not running on openliberty

Tags: open-liberty

I have a legacy websphere EE7 app I am attempting to convert to run on openliberty. It now seems to run on openliberty which is great.

However the integration tests do not seem to run. They hot compile, but do not run. The application is deployed as an EAR file.

The log is below with no evidence of the tests running when I hit enter.

```
[INFO] To run tests on demand, press Enter.
[INFO] Waiting up to 30 seconds to find the application start up or update message...
[INFO] CWWKM2010I: Searching for (CWWKZ0001I:|CWWKZ0003I:) in <app name removed>\logs\messages.log. This search will timeout after 30 seconds.
[INFO] CWWKM2015I: Match number: 1 is [19/07/22 18:06:21:660 NZST] 00000037 com.ibm.ws.app.manager.AppMessageHelper                      
A CWWKZ0001I: Application <my application> started in 17.692 seconds..
[INFO] Running integration tests...
[INFO] Integration tests finished.
[INFO]
[INFO] To run tests on demand, press Enter.
[INFO] Tests compilation was successful.

[INFO] Running integration tests...
[INFO] Integration tests finished.
[INFO]
[INFO] To run tests on demand, press Enter.

[INFO] Running integration tests...
[INFO] Integration tests finished.
[INFO]
[INFO] To run tests on demand, press Enter.
```

Has anyone got any tips on how I can get the tests to run when I press enter? They must be being called from something, or have their path set by something, or require some maven plugin configuration?

Comment: The simple guide at https://openliberty.io/guides/getting-started.html has an example POM you could try to pattern after.    It sounds like an issue with your failsafe/surefire plugin configurations.   I'd be happy to take a look if you could post your POM or a snippet.   You mention this is an EAR file.  Are you building a multi-module project or is it just an EAR module pulling in dependencies?   If it is multi-module you might need to give more detail:  which module holds the tests, which the server config (server.xml), etc.

Comment: Yes, it's a multimodule project. I'll post a stripped down example. I've had no issues getting the 'getting started' guides to work.

Comment: May or may not be helpful, but there is a multi-module guide which has tests: https://openliberty.io/guides/maven-multimodules.html#running-the-tests